# Unchecked cast from generic type to the same type

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-cast

The following code generates a warning `Unchecked cast: 'T' to 'U'` in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
interface A {}
class B<T extends A, U extends A> {
    void f() {
        final T t = null;
        final U u = (U) t;
    }
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since `T` and `U` are defined as the same type. What is the problem?

Comment: `T extends A, U extends A` doesn't mean that `T` and `U` are the same type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` and `U` are not defined as the same type. They are both defined as `extends A`, which means `T` and `U` can be unrelated classes that implement the `A` interface. Hence the cast is not safe.

The only safe cast you can do is to cast references of type `T` or `U` to type `A`. Of course you don't need such a cast. You can simply assign them to a variable of type `A`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why. Both `T` and `U` extend `A`, so why can't I cast from "a type that extends `A`" to "another type that extends `A`"? Before and after, the cast object will extend `A`.

Comment: @Nickkk `Integer` and `String` both implement `Serializable`; but you wouldn't expect to be able to cast an `Integer` to a `String`, right?

Comment: The example did it. I was thinking of the types `T` and `U` as being the same as `A`, but instead `T extends A` is a placeholder for a specific type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While both `T` and `U` extend `A`, they are not the same type. Hence you cannot cast from one to the other.

Consider:

```
class D implements A {}
class E implements A {}
B<D, E> b;
```

You cannot cast from D to E.

Answer (score 1):

**Parent:**

```
interface A {
}
```

**Child:**

```
class B implements A {

}

class C implements A {

}
```

In the above example A is parent B and C.

Example:

The below code will works fine.

```
  A a = new B();

  B b = (B)a;
```

This will trigger class Cast Exception.

```
  B b = new B();

  C c = (C) b;
```

You can't type cast with your Siblings type. This is because You may try to access the methods/properties that may present in the resultant class.

*Same thing can be to String,Integer,Object. Object is **parent**

Integer & String are the child for Object class but you cannot cast these classed.*

Answer (score 0):

```
    final T t = null;
    final U u = (U) t;
```

Although this is unchecked, this is actually safe, because `null` can be cast to any reference type without a `ClassCastException`.

However, the compiler doesn't consider the value of a non-null reference when you cast it: it's simply "some" `T`. This is an example of where you, the programmer, know more about the types than the compiler, because you know that `t == null`, so you can legitimately ask the compiler to trust you by adding casts and `@SuppressWarnings`.

But if `t` were non-null, this wouldn't always be safe. `T` and `U` are different types: they are "something that extends `A`" and "something (maybe the same, maybe not) that extends `A`".

To make this a little bit more concrete, here's an equivalent example:

```
class B<T extends Serializable, U extends Serializable> {
  U method(T t) {
    return (U) t;
  }
}

String s = new B<Integer, String>().method(1);
```

This will fail with a `ClassCastException`, because an `Integer` isn't a `String`.

If you don't want them to be different types, remove one of them (and, of course, the cast).